# Preimage of a sufficiently small set

Tags: measure-theory

I think the following claim is correct but I don't know how to prove it rigorously:
Assume $A_n\subset \mathbb{R}$ a sequence of measurable sets with $m(A_n)<\epsilon$ for sufficiently large $n$. $f$ is a continuous map. Then $m(f^{-1}(A_n))<\delta(\epsilon)$ (sufficiently small) for sufficiently large $n$. Here $m(\cdot)$ denote the Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not true. Consider $f(x)=0$ and the sequence $\{A_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ given by

$$A_n=\left[-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right].$$

Then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}m(A_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2}{n}=0,$$

but, as $0\in A_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}m(f^{-1}(A_n))=\lim_{n\to\infty}m(\mathbb{R})=\infty.$$